# Having an error that Unable to find explicit activity class (startactivity from activity to fragment)

Tags: android

my startactivity(i_back) has a problem , I am trying to startactivity from activity to fragment. so there is no need to declare in manifest since it is fragment so I don't know why I have the error  Thx in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare activity (inside `<application>` tag) in manifest like that:

```
<activity android:name=".addressbook.ContactsFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class `ContactsFragment` extends `Fragment`, you can't start it using `startActivity` method.

Check the docs on how to deal with fragments.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

---

If your class `ContactsFragment` extends `Activity`, you must declare it in AndroidManifest.xml inside `application` tag, just like that.

```
<activity android:name=".ContactsFragment"/>
```

Check if your class is inside any package.

Comment: Thank you :) then I made my ContactsFragment extend FragmentActivity then a lot of lines were in red , is there another way to start fragment..?

Comment: You must have a container inside your activity layout, then replace its content with a fragment.
Also, maybe the red lines when you extended `FragmentActivity` are due the context change. You must use `this` or `ContactsFragment.this` instead of `getActivity()` once `ContactsFragment` becomes the activity itself.